# Mosaic from MJPEG sources in VLC

Tags: streaming, vlc, mjpeg

I'm trying to set up a mosaic stream from multiple mjpeg sources and output it as yet another mjpeg. The matrix wizard in the web interface is either broken or just unclear, and the Mosaic tutorial on VLC website doesn't seem to help complete it. What I have so far is:

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled                                                       
setup channel1 input "http://192.168.1.100:8080/video"
setup channel1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=1},select=audio}                                                         

new channel2 broadcast enabled
setup channel2 input "http://192.168.1.100:8080/video"
setup channel2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=2,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=2},select=audio}                                                         

new channel3 broadcast enabled
setup channel3 input "http://192.168.1.100:8080/video"
setup channel3 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=3,height=144,width=180},select=video,dst=bridge-out{id=3},select=audio}                                                         

new background broadcast enabled
setup background option image-duration=-1
setup background input flower.png
setup background output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=MJPEG,vb=10000,scale=1}:bridge-in{delay=400,id-offset=100}:standard{access=http,mux=MPJPEG,dst=127.0.0.1:333/mosaic}

control background play
control channel1 play
control channel2 play
control channel3 play
```

This looks close to what it's supposed to be however not working. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
Igor

Comment: This is not a programming related question, please see http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you mean its not working, do you mean that you dont see the videos mossaiced in the output file? Personally, I got it working when I used rtsp streams but couldnt get it to work when I used http. You could try creating a mosaic from local files (on disk) to help exclude any network problems. Also, if your system is not capable enough, you'll get a video file with no mosaicced videos. Try just one stream to check if this is the problem. Lastly it will help if your background image, the video streams and the mosaic output video resolutions fits.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for starts! There are no communication issues as I see the mjpg stream directly in the browser, also can make a mosaic of four using simple html, so I guess system capability should be fine as well. My guess is that what works with rtsp needs some alteration to work with mjpg, and also might be my command-line syntax could be wrong, now it's 
`vlc -vvv --color -I qt --vlm-conf mosaic.vlm.conf --mosaic-width=360 --mosaic-height=288 --mosaic-keep-picture --mosaic-rows=2 --mosaic-cols=2 --mosaic-position=1 --mosaic-order=1,2,3,4 --ttl 12 --udp-caching 800`
will appreciate more advice! Tx!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify full path to the background picture; then change the line:
`setup background input flower.png`
to for example:
`setup background input /home/yourName/flower.png`

then you must know that `--udp-caching` option is not supported now; then omit it. Also I recommend you to remove `mosaic-keep-picture` option. 
I home this help.